# Clicking %%unsub_center_url%% link only unsubscribes user from LIST?

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscriber

If we use the `%%unsub_center_url%%` in an email, and a user clicks just that, and not the `Unsubscribe From All` button, the user is marked as "Unsubscribed" on the List, but not on All Subscribers.

Is this expected behaviour?  This is not a Publication list, so unsure why it does this.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending to Lists I assume and not Data Extension?

It's normal behaviour. Subscribers will be unsubscribed from the List as that is where the subscription status is held - unless they also unsubscribe from all (which then unsubscribes from All Subscribers list of the Business Unit or enterprise)

If your business process means you are creating a new list for every send, then you should reconsider your implementation approach.

Publication Lists are used for Data Extension sends to manage status,

Comment: I don't know if this is correct. If George is using lists then the subscriber status will impact the overall status of the subscriber. how come this is only impacting status only for a particular list. @George can you please explain how are you trying to send your emails.

Comment: This was a one-off - we normally send via Data Extensions.

A user took a list of openers to create a LIST and deployed to it, which is not our normal process.

Comment: this is correct. pub lists function to mimic List behavior for DE.  This is so that if a person unsubs from DE, they are not automatically unsubed from all. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_list_unsubscribe.htm&type=5